# Can the space shuttle use OMS engines during landing?

Tags: space-shuttle, landing, entry-descent-landing

Can the space shuttle use its OMS engines if the shuttle is short during the runway approach? Is fuel available for use in such a situation and will the engines provide reasonable thrust to get to the runway?

Comment: I would be surprised if they wouldn't immediately destroy themselves because of flow separation. They are vacuum engines, after all, not sea-level. The OMS engines for Orion (which are refurbished Shuttle OMS engines) are test-fired in a vacuum chamber. SpaceX recently tested a vacuum version of the Raptor at sea-level ambient pressure, but they had to run it at full throttle, and add additional bracing to the nozzle, to prevent it from destroying itself.

Comment: This https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/shutref/orbiter/oms/overview.html indicates 70k feet as lowest altitude to operate the OMS but not what physics that comes from.

Comment: @GremlinWrangler it's because the engine bells would collapse due to the low pressure inside / high pressure outside. That is indeed the answer.

Comment: I would expect this to work like "base bleed" in artillery shells. The exhaust wouldn't need to produce trust so much as reduce the wake drag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

As mentioned by @GremlinWrangler in a comment, the Orbital Maneuvering System (OMS) engines could not be fired below 70,000 ft (21 km) altitude.

> The minimum altitude for an OMS engine burn is 70,000 feet. Below this altitude, the
> pressure difference between the inside and the outside of the OMS engine nozzle could
> cause it to collapse.

Source: [Orbital Maneuvering System training manual](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/USA006500%20-%20Orbital%20Maneuvering%20System%20Workbook%20OMS%2021002.pdf), p. 3-18

Comment: I've just asked [How can firing a Space Shuttle OMS engine below 21 km cause it's nozzle to "collapse"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49772/12102)